# Aws chef node not able to execute chef run list

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I have installed chef workstation and chef server in my local machine and I'm able to connect chef node through workstation (node in Amazon EC2).

When I am bootstrapping node, chef node is not able to connect to chef server, I am always getting an error stating

> your chef server url not correct if url correct network down.

Please give me a solution, to execute run lists.

I am guising there is some HTTPS protocol problem

Bootstrap command:

```
Knife bootstrap 54.345.321.45  --ssh-user ubuntu --sudo --identity-file ~/.ssh/aws.pem --node-name awsnode1 --run-list 'recipe[create_folder]'
```

If I did a mistake in installation please provide information on how to install **chefdk** and **chefserver** in my PC and chef node in Amazon EC2.

What are pre required changes in my laptop and AWS to install properly?

Comment: If you want this for testing, you can use hosted chef - https://manage.chef.io/login

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you use Chef Server. If it's on your workstation, chances are that is hidden behind a NAT so the EC2 VM cannot talk to it. You need to install Chef Server on an actual server that is reachable from both the workstation and all client nodes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, kindly please let me know details about NAT,  I have installed chef on Ubuntu, with the following link: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/configuration-management/install-a-chef-server-workstation-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: That's 100% up to the details of your laptop, the network you're sitting on, etc.